# Webclient POST 405 Error in API

Tags: c#, .net, api, post, webclient

I've written some code a while back that handles `POST` requests. Suddenly it stopped working whilst I changed nothing in either the API (It still works fine with postman) nor the **C#** code. But I get a `405` error (method not allowed) when I run my code.
The login method:

```
public byte[] logInViaAPI(string email, string password)
        {
            var response = APIHandler.Post("http://myurlhere", new NameValueCollection() {
                {   "email", email          },
                {   "password", password    },
            });
            return response;
        }
```

This is my POST method:

```
public static byte[] Post(string uri, NameValueCollection pairs)
        {
            byte[] response = null;
            try
            {
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {

                    response = client.UploadValues(uri, pairs); //This is where I get my error
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex);
                return null;
            }
            return response;
        }
```

The error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   System.dll

Additional information:

> The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

I used [HTTP request with post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post) as a source (and some other topics too) but I cant seem to figure out the problem.

Comment: It started to fail probably due to an upgrade on the server.  Best method os determine the issue is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Capture good results with postman and compare http headers with your application that is not working.  Make you http headers look like postman headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question: I changed to protocol to HTTPS from HTTP, whilst still using the HTTP url.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is the use SecurityProtocol. Try this before the call:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```